# C++ - Template function using initializer_list as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, initializer-list

I wrote a simple function to calculate the min value of an `std::initializer_list` like this:

```
template<typename T>
inline T min(const std::initializer_list<T>& values) {
    T minValue = values[0];
    for ( const auto& v : values )
        if ( v < minValue ) minValue = v;

    return minValue;
}
```

But I get the following errors:

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'T'
>   error C2226: syntax error: unexpected type 'std::initializer<_Elem>'
>   error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>   error C2059: syntax error: ')'
>   error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'identifier'

I tried to change the `std::initializer_list` with an `std::vector` and there were no errors. Does this mean that we cannot define a template function using `std::initializer_list` as a parameter? I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note that `initializer_list` doesn't have `operator[]`. Note also that [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) exists.

Comment: @Barry There is nothing else to provide this is the exact code that gives these errors. Without even calling `min()` function

Comment: [really](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7acf72dcbc94641c)

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Barry This `min` is inside a different namespace. And even if I remove everything inside the function and just `return T();` I still get the same errors

Comment: Did you `#include <initializer_list>`?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I did

Comment: @jaggedSpire I am using visual studio. Maybe it's different, I am not really sure

Comment: Per wasthishelpful's answer, msvc2013 doesn't behave noticeably differently here. *Please* try to isolate your problem completely, as it seems you've not done so.

Comment: wait, all the online compilers are using version 19, which is for msvc2015...

Comment: @jaggedSpire: You don't get a compiler error because you never instantiated the template!

Comment: @AndyG I was responding to OP's claim that "Without even calling min() function", which I took to mean he wasn't instantiating it anywhere.

Comment: @jaggedSpire: Perhaps I should have read OPs comment first :/

Comment: @AndyG eh, I've done the same before. It's a pity it's so difficult to find an online version of vc++ 18 and verify if OP's problem stems from that compiler though. Alas, my license for msvc2013 has lapsed, so I can't even load it up and try it there.

Comment: The *really* weird thing is that msvc2013 and msvc2015 *don't* do any more than the barest of syntax checks on non-instantiated templates, as part of their broken two-phase lookup. [You can type in `template <typename> void BadTwoPhaseLookup(){ SHOULD NOT COMPILE; }`](http://rextester.com/ZACP77242) and it'll happily compile it so long as you don't instantiate the template. It's frankly bizarre to me that msvc2013 is throwing a fit over the comparatively well-formed, non-instantiated implementation of `min` he's got there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), `std::initializer_list` has no `operator[]`, so this line:

```
T minValue = values[0];
```

can not be valid. You can replace it with:

```
T minValue = *values.begin();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still get the same errors

Comment: I tested the code in rextester.com with visual compiler. It is working with a main function just executing `std::cout << (min({1, 2, 3}));`. You should edit your question with a complete example

Comment: Did you include `<initializer_list>`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful he said he did in the comments on the question.